# How to get pageviews data for a separate page in GoogleAnalytics API

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using [GoogleAnalytics API library](https://github.com/ronan-gloo/Codeigniter-Google-Analytics-library) on my Codeigniter site, but i didn't find there and on [Google API guide](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/dimsmets/dimsmets.html) - 
how to get results for a one exact page.

Say i've got page http://www.example.com/company/82808, and i make request to GA API and get pageviews and visitors metrics for this URL - example.com/company/8280.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Apply a filter for `ga:pagePath`

Include in the request:

Dimension: `ga:pagePath`

Metrics: `ga:pageviews,ga:visitors`

Filter: `filter=ga:pagePath==/company/82808` use this exact match if that is how the page is recorded in GA. If it's recorded like `/company/82808/index.php` then you can use `filter=ga:pagePath==/company/82808/index.php` or `ga:pagePath=~/company/82808` for a contains match.

Test out queries in Google's [Data Feed Query Explorer](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html)

Comment: actually author of a library gave me exact comment on github: https://github.com/ronan-gloo/Codeigniter-Google-Analytics-library/issues/4#issuecomment-3597501

Comment: Hey jk. i didn't find `ga:visitors` (in metrics) on `https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/`. Can you please tell me how can i view it there?